# How do I create a launch file?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, roslauch, begginer-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing the tutorial now. I am now [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch) at 1.2.2 - 1.2.5 .

I made a file (in the folder that the tutorial says) named turtlemimic.launch (with the code given). But when I run the code I get this error message :

```
[turtlemimic.launch] is neither a launch file in package [beginner_tutorials] nor is [beginner_tutorials] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

How do I make a .launch file??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206808/how-do-i-create-a-launch-file??/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) on 2015-04-07**:
Can you copy/paste the command that produced that error message?

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-04-07**:
@Morgan I run the command `$ roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch` , just as the tutorial says.

**Comment by [Amer Al-Radaideh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29188/amer-al-radaideh/) on 2017-01-28**:
for those who have this problem ([beginner_tutorials] is not a package or launch file name)
please follow this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be happening for a few reasons (I know some of these are obvious, I'm just going through the list of things I try to verify when debugging such a problem):

1. Have you sourced the `devel/setup.bash` from your workspace into your current shell ? Otherwise, roslaunch won't know where to look to find the beginner_tutorials files, including turtlemimic.launch   you can verify that your current shell knows about the beginner_tutorials location by running `rospack list | grep beginner_tutorials` and verifying that your package directory shows up in the location you expect.
2. Is the file named exactly turtlemimic.launch, and is it somewhere in the beginner_tutorials directory tree? Note that if it is somewhere in the workspace (e.g., the workspace root) rather than in the `src/beginner_tutorials` directory tree, roslaunch will not be able to find it.
3. Make sure the launch file is valid XML that starts with a `launch` tag.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-04-08**:
I did check all of that but maybe I was tired and did some mistake some where (had 7 terminals opened :P ). Now that I did everything from the beginning it worked just fine. Thanks for your help :)

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-04-08**:
@Morgan I just looked I did again a little better. Do I need to source devel/setup.bash at every new terminal I use?

**Comment by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) on 2015-04-08**:
Yes, every terminal that needs to work with the package(s) you are developing in your workspace needs to source the devel/setup.bash file from the workspace. I will typically set up a bash alias for the most common workspace I'm using, so you can just type "w" or whatever, to make it fast and easy.